# Is $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5+\sqrt{5}}) $ a Galois extension?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

> I am wondering if the number field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5+\sqrt{5}})=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is a Galois extension.

I think it is and I have the following argument, but it feels like a circular argument: I know that we have the subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ so we have one automorphism $\sigma$ that sends $\sqrt{5}$ to $\sqrt{-5}$. The other roots of the minimal polynomial over $\alpha$ are:
\begin{align*}
-\alpha \\
-i\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}} = \sigma(\alpha) \\
i \sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}} = \sigma(-\alpha)
\end{align*}
Clearly $-\alpha$ is also in $K$ and since $\sigma$ is an automorphism, $\sigma(\alpha)$ and $\sigma(-\alpha)$ must also. So we have a normal extension, hence a Galois extension. Is this a right argument or am I assuming something I cannot?

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with a choice of radicals $x = i \sqrt{5 - \sqrt{5}}$. Note that
$x^2 = - (5-\sqrt{5})$ so $x^2 + 5 = \sqrt{5}$, $(x^2 + 5)^2 = 5 $, and finally
$$x^4 + 10 x^2 + 20 =0$$
an irreducible equation with roots $\pm i \cdot \sqrt{5 \pm\sqrt{5}}$. We see that the different choices of radicals gives isommorphic extensions.

We want to know whether $K =\mathbb{Q}(x)= \mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt{5 - \sqrt{5}})$ is normal, equivalently, whether $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt{5 - \sqrt{5}})$  contains $i \sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5}}$. Recall that $x^2 + 5 = \sqrt{5}$ so $\sqrt{5} \in K$. 
Now, $i \sqrt{5 - \sqrt{5}} \cdot  i \sqrt{5 +  \sqrt{5}}= - \sqrt{ 25 - 5} = - \sqrt{20} = - 2 \sqrt{5} \in K$, so $i \sqrt{5 +  \sqrt{5}}$ also in $K$. We conclude that $K$ is normal, hence the extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois.

${\bf Added:}$. The roots of the equation $x^4 + 10 x^2 + 20 =0$  are $\pm x$ and $\pm ( 2x + \frac{10}{x})$. The Galois group acts transitively on the roots. If $\sigma(x) = -x$ then $\sigma( \pm( 2x + \frac{10}{x})) = \mp ( 2x + \frac{10}{x})$, so $\sigma$ is of order $2$. More interesting, consider $\sigma$ that takes $x$ to $2x + \frac{10}{x}$. Then $\sigma(2x + \frac{10}{x}) = 2 (2x + \frac{10}{x}) + \frac{10}{2x + \frac{10}{x}} $  and 
$$ 2 (2x + \frac{10}{x}) + \frac{10}{2x + \frac{10}{x}} - (-x) = \frac{5 (10  x^4+ 10 x^2 + 20)}{x ( x^2+5)}=0$$
so $\sigma^2(x) = -x$. Hence, this $\sigma$ is of order $4$, and since the Galois group is of order $4$, it will be cyclic with this $\sigma$ as generator.

Comment: Ok great! and now what are the automorphisms in the Galois group? At least we have identity and $\sigma_2$ that sends $\sqrt5$ to $-\sqrt5$. Are the other two $\sigma_3: \alpha \mapsto -\alpha$ and $\sigma_2\sigma_3$?

Comment: The extension is cyclic and ramified only at $5$, so must be the cyclotomic field $\Bbb Q(\zeta_5)$. It might be an amusing exercise to express $\sqrt{-5+\sqrt5}$ in terms of $\zeta_5$.

Comment: @Lubin: $\sigma_5^2 - \sigma_5^{-2} = 2 i \sin \frac{4 \pi}{5}$. Now $\sin  \frac{4 \pi}{5} = \sqrt{ \frac{5 - \sqrt{5}}{8}}$.  So $\sigma_5^2 - \sigma_5^{-2}= \frac{i \sqrt{5 - \sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$ ..

Answer (score 1):

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha = i\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $(x^2+5)^2-5 = x^4+10x^2+20 $ and the conjugated roots are $\pm i\sqrt{5\pm\sqrt{5}}$. Since
$$ -i\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}} = \frac{\sqrt{20}}{i\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}} = \frac{2\sqrt{5}}{\alpha} = 2\cdot\frac{\alpha^2+5}{\alpha} = 2\alpha+\frac{10}{\alpha}$$
the extension is clearly normal, hence a Galois extension.